# Accessing remote database using php

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I have xampp installed in my system and wants to connect to a remote mysql database using php. I have access to the remote system.

```
mysqli_connect("hostname", "username", "password", "database name")
```

So, apart from providing the details in the above line of code should I make any changes in any settings file or something?

Comment: What is the error your getting?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on whether you are using a framework/cms or not. Those usually come with settings file but if you're using raw PHP code then that line above should be sufficient